# Print success notice in their own div depending on the form that I sent

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have this script that allows me to send data to the database without reloading the page. The form data is sent to file process.php.
At the end of the process, inside the div box of the form is printed a notice that everything went ok

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $(document).on('submit', '.formValidation', function(){
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'submit.php',
                data : data,
                success :  function(data){                      
                    $(".formValidation").fadeOut(500).hide(function(){
                        $(".result").fadeIn(500).show(function(){
                            $(".result").html(data);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Page success.php:

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_".$key."(nome_".$key.") VALUES ('$value')";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);
}

print "ok";
```

And the div box for the notice `<div class="result"></div>`

**The problem:** I have many div box with a form and when I print the notice of success, it happen into all the `<div>`, because the call notification is always `.result`

```
success: function(data){                        
    $(".formValidation").fadeOut(500).hide(function(){
        $(".result").fadeIn(500).show(function(){
            $(".result").html(data);
        });
    });
}
```

**What I want**: Print the success notice in its own div depending on the form that I sent.

Thanks

EDIT: The html interested

```
     <form id="myform2" class="formValidation" name="myform2" action="" method="post"></form>   <!-- this is the form for the <div> in html5 -->
        <div class="widget-body">
            <div class="widget-main">
                    <div>
                <label for="form-field-select-1">Comune</label>
                            <select name="comune" class="form-control" id="form-field-select-1" form="myform2">
                              <option value="">Seleziona...</option>
                                                <?php       
                         $comune = "SELECT * FROM tbl_comune ORDER BY nome_comune ASC";
                             $result_comune = dbQuery($comune); 
                               if (dbNumRows($result_comune) > 0) {
                                  while($row_comune = dbFetchAssoc($result_comune)) {
                                      extract($row_comune);
                                 ?>   

                                                            <option value="<?php echo $id_comune; ?>"><?php echo $nome_comune; ?></option>
                                                             <?php
                               }
                              } else {
                            ?>
                              <option value="">Non ci sono dati</option>
                                                           <?php
                             }
                             ?>
                          </select>
                                                    </div>

                                                <hr>    
                                        <div class="widget-body">
                                            <div class="widget-main">
                                                <div> 

       <input type="text" name="comune" id="comune" value="" placeholder="Aggiungi Comune" form="myform2">  
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" form="myform2"> 

   <div class="result"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                     </div>
                                         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the form is in a div and the result is next to the form, you can do sibling:

`$form.next(".result").html(data);`

or elsewhere in the same parent:

`$form.parent().find(".result").html(data);`

or in your case

`$form.find(".result").html(data);`

Like this - note I have removed all the unnecessary hiding.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('submit', '.formValidation', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $form = $(this); // save a pointer to THIS form
    $result = $form.find(".result");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'submit.php',
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $result.html(data);
        $form.fadeOut(500, function() {
          $result.fadeIn(500)
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform2" class="formValidation" name="myform2" action="" method="post"></form>
<!-- this is the form for the <div> in html5 -->
<div class="widget-body">
  <div class="widget-main">
    <div>
      <label for="form-field-select-1">Comune</label>
      <select name="comune" class="form-control" id="form-field-select-1" form="myform2">
        <option value="">Seleziona...</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="widget-main">
        <div>

          <input type="text" name="comune" id="comune" value="" placeholder="Aggiungi Comune" form="myform2">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" form="myform2">

          <div class="result"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your script but does not work. On submit nothing happens.

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful comment. Any errors in the console? I do not have your HTML so I just guessed

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right! No in the console i don't have any error. I have edited the main code so you can see the HTML that i use...Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but what is the update?  `jquery.min.js`? I have that line on the <head> of the page

Comment: I changed to $form.find

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90918/discussion-between-ogum-and-mplungjan).